# double tap for delphi assign command, and extra mouse buttons for copy and paste through autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I'm lost in the wonderful world of Auto Hotkey language what and the rest...

I'm trying to make a double click of the ";" key result in a ":=" (Delphi's assign command) [or an Ctrl + ; ===> := ,also fine]

I would also like to make my two extra mouse buttons, stay forward and backward, but on double-click be copy and paste.

I have this: but as it is now, the ; character doesn't type AT ALL, and the double tap, doesn't give me a :=   ...

```
`;::DoubleTap("^;",250)

DoubleTap(key,TimeVar=300) 
{
    If (A_ThisHotkey==A_PriorHotkey && A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < TimeVar)
        Send %key%
    else
        Send {%A_ThisHotkey%}
    return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a acceptable solution, although I don't really understand it yet... my [;] key on short press is [;] and on long press is [:=], fine! something works, I was really just hacking to get it to work, I don't exactly know why it works... CODE:

```
$`;::
keywait,`;
if A_TimeSinceThisHotkey >= 250 ;
    Send {:}{=}
Else
    Send {;}
Return
```

Still searching for double click copy and paste...